# How to add list of Markers in google map (Flutter) from Json

Tags: json, flutter, google-maps, dart

```
 Future <void> _onMapCreated() async{
  final mapMarkersInfo = await APIService().getPlaces();
  mapMarkersInfo.forEach((element) { 
    allmarkers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(element.title),
      draggable: false,
      onTap: (){print(element.title);},
      position: LatLng(element.latitude,element.longitude),
    ));
  });
}
```

I am using this get the data and add markers (It is in the init state) There are no errors in the code while compiling but markers are not showing up in the maps. Could you please tell me how to update these markers from a json ?

Comment: Are you updating screen?, try calling setState((){}), or let me know if you are using an state management like provider or bloc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe a simple **setState(() {})** call should do the trick once you have pushed/added all the markers to the allmarkers.